Typings with promise settled results
I'm trying to write a function that takes an array of PromiseSettledResult (the type returned by Promise.allSettled) and returns an array of fulfilled values or rejected reasons:
function unwrapResults<T>(results: ReadonlyArray<PromiseSettledResult<T>>): Array<T> {
    return results.map((result) => result.status === "fulfilled" ? result.value : result.reason);
}

It's working in the following example:
const results = await Promise.allSettled([
    Promise.resolve(1),
    Promise.resolve("ok"),
    Promise.reject(new Error("error"))
]);

const unwrappedResults = unwrapResults<number | string | Error>(results);

The problem is that:

I need to explicitly give the union of all possible settled results types as unwrapResults type.
The elements inside unwrappedResults will be of type number | string | Error.

Is there a way to improve this? Ideally, I would expect less manual typings in the function call and unwrappedResults[0] to be a number, unwrappedResults[1] to be a string, and unwrappedResults[2] to be an Error.

I'm not sure that you can. Something like https://tsplay.dev/WP2DYN would get you [number, string, never] (as a Promise.reject is a Promise<never>) but in realistic usage you're not going to know ahead of time whether a given entry will resolve or not, so you'd have to make all of them T | Error.

this is how you'd add |Error to them all

I am going to say the reason it doesn't work the way you expect is due to limitations in typescript regarding how generics and the union types that are being checked. Specifically because PromiseSettledResult<string | number> is not identical to PromiseSettledResult<string> | PromiseSettledResult<number>, the unions end up with slightly different structures as they are represented by typescript but the .value field will both end up being string | number
So to get this to work we'd have to move our generics up a level and represent the PromiseSettledResult type and then extract the .value field from the generic using a conditional type. something like this:
type UnwrappedSettled<T extends PromiseSettledResult<any>> = T extends PromiseFulfilledResult<infer V> ? V : Error 
function unwrapOneResult<T extends PromiseSettledResult<unknown>>(result: T): UnwrappedSettled<T>{
    return result.status === "fulfilled" ? result.value : result.reason
}
async function test(){
    const results = await Promise.allSettled([
        Promise.resolve(1),
        Promise.resolve("ok"),
        Promise.reject(new Error("error"))
    ]);
    const unwrapped = results.map(unwrapOneResult)
    // ^? const unwrapped: (string | number | Error)[]
}

note that a necessary part for this to work properly is that T extends PromiseFufilledResult<infer V> will be applied to every element in the union of T individually and then the union of the result is returned, this is how we get around the part that PromiseFulfilledResult<string> | PromiseFulfilledResult<number> was acting differently, you can kind of think of it as map for type unions.
Another technicality that makes this work is that in javascript the rejection reason can technically be any, to avoid this completely destroying our typesafety we explicitly say that the type for a rejected result is Error on the other branch of that conditional type. Technically Promise.reject(new Error("error")) doesn't retain any type information about the reason so handling it inherently has to be not typesafe. :'(
So then writing your unwrapResults is similarly doable with a mapped type as the result so it tries to retain tuples when possible.
function unwrapResults<T extends Array<PromiseSettledResult<any>>>(results: [...T]): {[K in keyof T]: UnwrappedSettled<T[K]>} {
    // @ts-expect-error the following isn't assignable to the mapped type, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29841#issuecomment-619505904 for why this isn't allowed in the general case.
    return results.map(unwrapOneResult)
}

(The unwrapOneResult can be inlined in this version)

Awesome! I'm both very grateful for your explanations and proposed solution, and afraid by how much I still have to learn! Could you please elaborate a bit about the [...T] parameter type, or point me to the doc about this syntax?
Thank you!

[...T] is functionally identical to just T but has slightly different generic resolution that I unfortunately don't have any official reference for. Just prior experience that that is what works

also look at the example jonrsharpe posted as a comment and the modified version I just commented below theirs, the relevant documentation for mapped tuple types is here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays
